# Vote for our first Question of the Week for the UX blog!

Tags: discussion, blog

Before we start our blog I'd like to gather votes for our first Question of the Week entry!

To participate just **submit an answer stating the question, why it's worthy of a blog post and if you'd be interested in writing it**. You don't have to volunteer to write a post to suggest it, just let us know if you're interested in writing the post yourself.

**Vote on questions you'd like to see as QotW blog posts**. Our bloggers reserve the right to chose the specific question we write about but the suggestion thread will be our first stop.

Take a peek at the [Hot Questions of the week](https://ux.stackexchange.com/?tab=week) list for inspiration but note the post doesn't have to be from that list; it doesn't even have to be from the last week. It just has to be an interesting, deep question with more to explore; enough for a blog post!

Answer (score 5):

The obvious question seems to be [Is UX better marketing than marketing?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21765/is-ux-better-marketing-than-marketing)

This is definitely a popular question and there's a lot of in-depth analysis that could be had here. It however does already have a pretty good answer by [Michael Zuschlag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/21776/7627)

Comment: -1, because I believe the question is too open-ended to address satisfactorily. What is meant by 'marketing'? What is meant by 'better'? What's the distinction between the two fields?

Comment: +1 I disagree with @JimmyBreck-McKye because the blog is the perfect place to discuss such a question. Open-ended questions are much better suited to blog opinion pages than they are on the main site. Simply *because* there is no correct answer means that an valid point-of-view can be put forward on the blog and any disagreements by readers can be left as comments and discussed there. This possibly even allows for future blog-posts as a 'rebuttal' to the original one.

Comment: @JonW - open-ended questions are rejected from SE because they can't be handled without extended discussion, and lack a clear scope. I can't see those problems going away just because we're writing on the blog. Blog posts have to be pointed, have to have a well defined question that they engage with substantially. I don't think that's possible with this topic.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye That's why it's more suitable to a blog, precicely *because* it doesn't have to be 'an answer' but just a commentary / discussion piece on it.

Comment: @JonW - do the readers of our blog want that kind of discussion? Personally, I'm always disappointed by blog posts that talk around a topic and don't provide actionable points. Who are the readers of our blog and what sorts of content do they want? We have to think about them - not just the theoretical limits of the blog post form.

Comment: I'm definitely of two minds here, but @JimmyBreck-McKye has an excellent point: I'm always disappointed by blog posts that talk around a topic and don't provide actionable points.  Personally, I HATE posts that give some details on A Thing and then ask the [inevitably silent] users what they think about A Thing.  If we're going to post on more open-ended topics like this, I'd rather see a point-counterpoint format used in the article.  If we can't give a single answer, we need to at least provide a thorough analysis from all sides.

Comment: @Karen - I think the 'A vs B' format could be a good way to give shape to this kind of nebulous topic.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is: [If a microsite uses the same logo as the main site, which "home" should it link to?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21763/if-a-microsite-uses-the-same-logo-as-the-main-site-which-home-should-it-link)

It's a question just begging for loads of examples and critiquing of existing sites, and for us to provide alternative suggestions and improvements to such sites (reddit.com being one such site, as mentioned by Ben in a comment on that question).

Answer (score 2):

I vote for [How to prove to client that blind users can also use his e-commerce website?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-prove-to-client-that-blind-users-can-also-use-his-e-commerce-website)

Because it has a tangible case (or a type of case), that can be used as a guideline for an accessible e-commerce websites article. I would be more than pleased to do some more research on the subject and write something.